# How to change the path of a falling sprite and let the sprite fall in curve way into a specific position in Andengine?

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I am having a sprite which falling to bottom.. Now in the touch action I want to change the path of that sprite and let it fall in a curve way(projectile manner).. Please suggest me what should  use..